# Command not found in tcsh

Tags: linux, tcsh

I have trouble with this code. Are my assigns properly done? I gave "q: Command not found.Badly placed ()'s."

```
#!/bin/tcsh 

set h = 0
set q = 0
set a = 0

foreach val ( $* )
  if ($val == "-h")then
    h = 1
  endif
  if ($val == "-q")then
    q = 1
  endif
  if ($val != "-h") && ($val != "-q")then
    a = 1
  endif
end
```

Comment: you need spaces surrounding your `()` chars. Also worth checking to see if https://shellcheck.net will process your `#!/bin/tcsh` file and flag any other problems. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter AFAIK, shellcheck only understands sh and bash.

Comment: @Shawn : Yep, just checked, doesn't support tcsh (or csh or ... ;-) ). Also lists that is supports `ksh`. .... Didn't have time before. Good luck to all!  .... Fix those `( statements )` so the have spaces around the `()`s.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comments about the `()`s and spaces, here is a version that works:

```
#!/bin/tcsh 

set h = 0
set q = 0
set a = 0

foreach val ( $* )
  if ($val == "-h") then
    set h = 1
  endif
  if ($val == "-q") then
    set q = 1
  endif
  if ($val != "-h" && $val != "-q") then
    set a = 1
  endif
end
```

1. Added spaces after `)`s
2. Put `&&` within the `()`s
3. Use `set` to set variables. Bourne shell just has `x=y` but *csh requires `set x=y`.

You might also want to look into `getopt` -- if you have a Linux or GNU version of that command available, it can make option parsing a lot more standardized.